# Can Apple spell correctly?

Tags: orthography

There's an ad appearing in the paper lately (in Aus) for Apple's iphone and its siri-thing.

The headline of the add says: "What's my day look like?"

To me that doesn't look like proper english. I would say "What does my day look like" or "What is my day looking like" but not this hybrid between of the two.

Am I correct or can Apple actually spell correctly?

Comment: Why the downvote(s)?

Comment: General reference; look up [the definition of "what's"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/what's?s=t) and one finds that it can mean *what does*. (Not an explanation for the downvote, by the way.)

Comment: An advertisement targeted at Australian readers cannot use copy that Australians do not understand and identify with.  Bad "copy"?

Comment: I would add to @Mahnax' explanation that the question's use of "spelling" is nonsensical. "What does my day look like" and "what is my day looking like" are not different *spellings* of "what's my day look like". That's like saying that "automobile" is the correct spelling of "car". You can ask whether the contraction "what's" is *grammatical* there, but *spelling* "what's" as "what's" is absolutely correct. (Unlike spelling "English" as "english" or "ad" as "add", I might add.)

Comment: @Kris "what's" is a common contraction of "what does" in many forms of English, including Australian (my own variant), British (the variant where I live) and American English. Think of the song "What's love got to do with it?".

Comment: @mikemaccana "What's love got to do with it?" = "What **has** love got to do with it?" HTH

Comment: @Kris It could go either way. "What does love got to do with it?" (ignoring that 'got to do with it' isn't correct anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In everyday speech people often contract "*What does*" into "*What's*" and Apple is performing speech recognition on people's everyday speech patterns- not on grammatically correct textbook writing.

Comment: Is it particular to the US? I've never heard anyone say it in Aus or the UK

Comment: From what I can tell, Apple is doing quite a good job given that *it's hard to wreck a nice beach*.

Comment: It could very well be just a US thing.  I don't have enough exposure to other English-speaking regions to be able to say for sure.

Comment: I can't really find any reference of does contracting to 's anywhere (plenty on do not). Has anyone got examples of this?

Comment: @Ben What’s your mom think about all this?

Comment: @tchrist She would think that some damn bad spelling :) (never heard anyone say that)

Comment: @Ben It’s not a matter of spelling; it’s a matter of speaking. And that’s how people speak. I’m sorry if it bothers you. “Where’s that go when you’re done with it?” is another. It’s not even considered substandard: ***’s*** can be an abbreviation for *has*, for *is*, or for *does*.  If you don’t like it, you can make up things that people don’t really say and write those, pretending they did. Seems a dumb idea to me, though.

Comment: @tchrist. Not sure what you mean in your last point but but fair enough of the spelling, my bad

Comment: I've heard it in New Zealand.  Not sure about Australia or any other English-speaking country.

Comment: Has 'people' been redefined recently?

Comment: Born and bred in the US: I've never heard "What's..." used as a contraction for "What does..."

Comment: @dj18: what part of the US?  Don't you hear/say things like: "*What's your wife think of that idea*?" or "*What's it do?*"

Comment: @Jim - NYC area. Nope, I definitely don't say it. The example sentences here sound slangy to my ears - if I heard someone speak such a way I'd understand what they're saying but think it improper.

Comment: @dj18 - Wow, NYC,  I grew up less than 200 hundred miles upstate from NYC and it was the norm there.

Comment: Here it is:  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/whats  **3.**  *Informal* what does (as in:) "what's he want?" orig. Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Ed.